# ASP.NET issue with css

Tags: asp.net

**Hi.**
I have studied asp.net(we learn it ASP.NET Web Forms) and know the CSS But how Link between them
should i write css and finish it then connected with asp.net or what and please if anyone have book or anything help me .
thanks.

Comment: css is used for html styling. It is not a part of asp .net. Just read basics of css and keep your focus on asp .net. you can learn css whenever it required in near future...........

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Web pages function as HTML pages at run time. You can therefore use cascading style sheets (CSS) to set the appearance of any elements on the page other than Web server controls. In addition, you can define ASP.NET themes that include cascading style sheet settings, and then apply themes to pages or to your site

you can refer this link to know more on this topic  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4kete56.aspx